# How to send notification from service?

Tags: android, service, notifications

Hai i try to make application can show notification from service, but why notification only shown when application is opened? my service is starting right, i have no idea about this.

This is my code :

```
 public class ServiceBaru extends Service {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences3;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor3;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2;
    Timer time = new Timer();
    String url_baru, url_default, url_pakai;
    int idl_modif, ids_modif;
    static String idl = "";
    static String ids = "";
    Context mContext;
    public ServiceBaru() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        sharedPreferences2 = getSharedPreferences("semua_url", MODE_PRIVATE);
        url_baru = sharedPreferences2.getString("url_masuk", "");
        sharedPreferences3 = getSharedPreferences("id_keluar", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor3 = sharedPreferences3.edit();
        url_default = "192.168.1.215";
        if(url_baru.equals("")){
            url_pakai = url_default;
        }
        else {
            url_pakai = url_baru;
        }
           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
     DapatId getid = new DapatId();
                getid.execute();
            }

        }, 1000);


        System.out.println("Hallo Dari Services");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

  public class DapatId extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://" + url_pakai + "/www/index.php/ambilid").build();
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    //Sengaja Kosong
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    //idl Menunjukkan Id Baru
                    // ids menunjukkan id lama dari shared preferences
                    sharedPreferences3 = getSharedPreferences("id_keluar", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    editor3 = sharedPreferences3.edit();
                    idl = response.body().string();
                    idl_modif = Integer.parseInt(idl);
                    ids_modif = sharedPreferences3.getInt("idpertama", 0);
                    if(ids_modif==0) {
                        ids = idl;
                        ids_modif = Integer.parseInt(ids);
                        editor3.putInt("idpertama", ids_modif);
                        editor3.commit();
                    }
                    else{
                        if(idl_modif>ids_modif){
                            NotificationCompat.Builder notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logoaaagunung).setContentTitle("ggahaMobile").setContentText("Ada Data Baru Yang Perlu Approve");
                            Intent notifklik = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            PendingIntent contentnotif = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notifklik, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                            notif.setContentIntent(contentnotif);
                            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                            notificationManager.notify(1, notif.build());
                            editor3.putInt("idpertama", idl_modif);
                            editor3.commit();
                            System.out.println(idl_modif + ids_modif);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

    }
```

and i my activity :

```
 Intent service = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, ServiceBaru.class);
                                startService(service);
```

This is my logcat:

```
> W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
> W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
> W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
> W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
> W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: when is the code run. when the service is started right? How do you start service?

Comment: @Raghunandan i edit my question, please check it.

Comment: @Raghunandan yes the service is start

Comment: you can easily check by putting logs in asynctask.

Comment: please, can you explain more about what should i write in my log?

Comment: you can log anything. its just to confirm that your asynctask is running. Also since you are using service there is nothing to update in ui. So using threads handler thread would be better choice i guess